# Why doesn't /proc take up disk space?

Tags: unix, disk-space, proc

Why doesn't `/proc` take up disk space?

When I put `sudo du -sh /proc` it return `0`.

I think that is something related to its purpose, but I'm not sure.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why doesn't `/proc` take up disk space?

Because it is a 'virtual filesystem', and doesn't store data in the same way as a filesystem for a hard drive:

> /proc is very special in that it is also a virtual filesystem. It's sometimes referred to as a process information pseudo-file system. It doesn't contain 'real' files but runtime system information (e.g. system memory, devices mounted, hardware configuration, etc). For this reason it can be regarded as a control and information centre for the kernel. In fact, quite a lot of system utilities are simply calls to files in this directory. For example, 'lsmod' is the same as 'cat /proc/modules' while 'lspci' is a synonym for 'cat /proc/pci'. By altering files located in this directory you can even read/change kernel parameters (sysctl) while the system is running.

From the [Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html); which has a fuller explanation of the `proc` filesystem and what various parts refer to (a bit beyond the scope of this question).

Red Hat also have [an explanation page about the parts of `proc`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/ch-proc.html) which is a bit shorter and ptoentally more manageable. There is also some general information on [Wikipedia about `procfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs).

Since it only contains (and controls) ephemeral information, it doesn't take up any space.